# zip two file with same content, but final md5sum is different

Tags: macos, zip, md5

I have the following operation on my mac:

```
$ echo "dgrgrrgrgrg" > test1.txt
```

after a few seconds, copy test1.txt:

```
$ cp test1.txt test2.txt
$ ls -l
total 16
-rw-r--r--  1 hqfy  staff  12 Mar 31 10:18 test1.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 hqfy  staff  12 Mar 31 10:19 test2.txt
```

now chech md5sum:

```
$ md5 *.txt
MD5 (test1.txt) = 8bab5a3e202c901499d83cb25d5a8c80
MD5 (test2.txt) = 8bab5a3e202c901499d83cb25d5a8c80
```

it's obvious that test1.txt and test2.txt have the same md5sum, now I zip these two files:

```
$ zip -X test1.zip test1.txt
    adding: test1.txt (deflated 8%)
$ zip -X test2.zip test2.txt
    adding: test2.txt (deflated 8%)
$ ls -l
total 32
-rw-r--r--  1 hqfy  staff   12 Mar 31 10:18 test1.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 hqfy  staff  127 Mar 31 10:22 test1.zip
-rw-r--r--  1 hqfy  staff   12 Mar 31 10:19 test2.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 hqfy  staff  127 Mar 31 10:23 test2.zip
```

size of test1.zip and test2.zip are the same, but when I check md5sum:

```
$ md5 *.zip
MD5 (test1.zip) = af8783f96ce98aef717ecf6229ffb07e
MD5 (test2.zip) = 59e752a03a2930adbe7f30b9cbf14561
```

I've googled it, using zip with option -X, but it did not work in my case, how can I create the two zip files with the same md5sum?

Comment: sorry I asked a stupid question, that's because filename is different in zip file

Comment: Did you try with the same file name?
And/or zipping the same file twice and then comparing the two zip archives?

Answer (score 3):

I know that this question is very old, but I may have an answer for you:
The timestamps for the two files (which are very obviously different) are included in the `.zip` file. That is why the `md5sum`s are different. If you can somehow remove those timestamps, then the `md5sum`s will be the same.

Also note that macOS adds a folder (`__MACOSX`) to a zip file that contains extra metadata and such. That may also be the issue.

Comment: didn't work (removed both from the .txt and .zip)

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from the [zip](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zip) man page here..

> With -X, zip strips all old fields and only includes the Unicode and
>   Zip64 extra fields (currently these two extra fields cannot be
>   disabled).

So, a different md5sum is expected when zipping (even with `-X`).